# Rust struct update syntax without taking ownership

Tags: rust

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Car {
    company: String,
    model: String,
    cost: i32
}

fn main() {
    let car1 = Car {
        company: String::from("Ford"),
        model: String::from("123xyz"),
        cost: 50000
    };
    let car2 = Car {
        model: String::from("987pqr"),
        cost: 47000,
        ..car1
    };
    println!("{:#?}", car2);
    println!("{:#?}", car1.company);
}
```

Here compiler correctly tells me:

```
println!("{:#?}", car1.company);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
move occurs because `car1.company` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I understand that String instance is on the heap and that is why it cannot be copied, ownership was moved to the `car2.company`. I can solve this use-case by something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Car {
    company: String,
    model: String,
    cost: i32
}

fn main() {
    let car1 = Car {
        company: String::from("Ford"),
        model: String::from("123xyz"),
        cost: 50000
    };
    let car2 = Car {
        model: String::from("987pqr"),
        cost: 47000,
        ..car1.clone()
    };
    println!("{:#?}", car2);
    println!("{:#?}", car1.company);
}
```

**Question 1**: Is there a better way to do this?

---

Now my problem with this is that if the struct had many fields clone would create a copy of the car1 instance of the struct just to use its values to be assigned to the car2 instance of struct which itself will store the values.
If x is the memory required to store an instance of the `struct Car`,

- car1: x
- car1.clone: x
- car2: x

3x memory required where technically only 2x memory should have been needed.

**Question 2**: After `car2` is instantiated will `car1.clone()` go out of scope and hence relinquish the memory?

If yes: this method of clone would be fine as only temporary one extra x memory is needed.

If no: then is there a way to achieve this goal without needed the extra x memory or taking ownership of the binding itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially asking if `..car1.clone()` performs a partial clone, and only clones the missing fields, i.e. `company` for `car2`.

Would that be a possible optimization? Possibly, but [`clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) could do *anything*, so it might not be as cut an dry to perform a "partial `clone()`". So the answer is no, `car1.clone()` is cloned entirely.

> Question 1: Is there a better way to do this?

I'm assuming that you're using the update syntax (`..`), because you have significantly more fields. However, if not, then to avoid needlessly cloning `model`. Then you can explicitly clone and assign `car1.company`.

However, I think you already know this. But if you want to avoid the needless clone of `model`. Then this is the alternate solution.

```rust
let car2 = Car {
    company: car1.company.clone(),
    model: String::from("987pqr"),
    cost: 47000,
};
```

> Question 2: After `car2` is instantiated will `car1.clone()` go out of scope and hence relinquish the memory?

Yes. `model` from `car1.clone()` is dropped immediately after the assignment to `car2`. However, `company` is of course not dropped, as that is moved to `car2`.